# Is there any other idiom for "Hundred blows of goldsmith is comparable to one blow of iron-smith"?

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

The idiom `Hundred blows of goldsmith is comparable to one blow of iron-smith` comes from a hindi idiom *"Sau sunar ki, ek lohar ki"*. Literal meaning is

> *One powerful blow is comparable to a hundred smaller blows*.

The figurative meaning is

> *One tactic from a smart man is equal to the hundreds tactics of an idiot.*

Or can be used in a fighting/boxing

> One knockout is better than hundred punches.

I'm looking for another idiom or small phrase to use.

Comment: There's a reasonably close Japanese proverb that I think translates to English a lot better. ["Better than a thousand days of diligent study is one day with a great teacher."](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22thousand+days+of+diligent+study%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Comment: ...and the Judeo-Christian tradition, Leviticus 26:8 [And five of you shall chase an hundred, and an hundred of you shall put ten thousand to flight](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Leviticus+26%3A7-8&version=KJV)

Comment: Better a diamond with a flaw than a pebble without. -
Confucius

Comment: The goldsmith / ironsmith thing confused me. I assumed it meant that goldsmith's blows were worth more, since they were striking a considerably more malleable metal. A single blow of an ironsmith wouldn't achieve nearly as much on his hard substrate.

Comment: Not worth more, but lighter and more frequent.  A jeweler is using a tiny hammer and going tap tap, while an ironsmith is using a sledge and going bang!

Comment: One hundred? How quaintly ... metric.

Comment: If the goldsmith applies his or her dainty blows to a hot piece of iron, nothing will be achieved; it is not comparable to striking the iron once with an ironsmith's instrument and blow. However, the goldsmith can use one hundred dainty blows to do some analogous operation on a gold ingot that the ironsmith does with one blow. The goldsmith doesn't have to worry about the gold cooling off, because it's being worked  cold.

Answer (score 3):

A nice Biblical analog is from Ecclesiasties 10:10.

> If the ax is dull and its edge unsharpened, more strength is needed, but skill will bring success.

Not quite along the same lines, but similar imagery to your idiom comes up in Proverbs 17:10.

> A reproof entereth more into a wise man than an hundred stripes into a fool.

Answer (score 2):

There is a similar and very common idiom in English:

> Quality over quantity

This is often taught using various Aesop's tales and is rather ingrained in American culture. It appears to differ slightly from the idiom you have translated in the sense that "quality over quantity" has less to do with *tactics* and more to do with *value*.

A more tactics based idiom is:

> Measure twice; cut once

This means that taking time to plan out a strategy will reduce costs in the long run. It is better to do it the right way the first time.

This loses the sense of quality or inherent superiority contained in the comparison between two different *things* (i.e., the smart man versus the idiot) but the general idea is similar.

A third idiom that, again, gets somewhat close:

> Penny wise; pound foolish

This cautions against the habit of obsessing over every single detail and, as a consequence, costing yourself more in the process. It keys on the definition of "penny" as a smaller monetary unit than a "pound". The Americanism would be "penny wise; dollar foolish."

These last two idioms have plenty of variants that apply in specific circumstances. One more I remember off the top of my head is "Lost the battle but won the war."

---

In the end, I would claim that "quality over quantity" is the most similar but, depending on your intended usage, the other idioms quoted here would also be acceptable.

Answer (score -2):

The closest I can get to the figurative meaning is "practice makes perfect", which of course is less close still to the literal meaning.

(As to the goldsmith vs. the ironsmith, that only makes me think of an entirely different idiom, "apples to oranges", as these are two very different professions with very different skill sets. I for one wouldn't want an ironsmith with his powerful blows anywhere near my precious jewellery. I fully understand that idioms don't have to actually make any sense, but still.)

Comment: I think you didn't get the meaning, I have added another explanation.

Comment: I think I got the meaning just fine (even though the four alternatives you provide are actually all rather different). What I am saying is that there is no exact equivalent I can think of, and mentioning the closest I can come to it. The closest can still be far.